# How can you visualise standardisation of any distribution?

Tags: statistics

I do understand the fact that $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is changing a distribution from a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$ to a distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, but I cannot visualise this transformation. 
I can understand the fact that for some distribution, this scaling is making easier to calculate certain values, but is there some intuitive example that could clarify this ?

Comment: You may be overthinking.  Look at a normal curve with mean and variance and see what happens with the transformation.  The curve is centered around zero and shrunk to a particular size.

Comment: Substract $\mu$ is equal to $\mu -\mu = 0$ that is the media of a normal distribution of media $0$

Answer (score 0):

To understand what happens with the mean, you need to see the distribution as a signal, then you see that subtracting the mean to $x$ does shift it back to zero (shift to the left when you subtract something).

Then you still have the variance, note that when you multiply a Gaussian r.v. times a constant, the squared constant shows up next to the variance of the transformed r.v. Thus, you may see that it may get the signal narrower or wider, depending on that constant. Then, to get the signal back to its original shape you need to 'normalize it', so that you do the inverse operation by dividing the dummy variable by the standard deviation.